# HH:MM:SS (Time Duration) Maximum Value

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file with 4 million rows. One of the columns(ride_length) has a time format as HH:MM: SS. I want to get the max value of the column. Some of the commands I tried and the error messages are as below. What should be the command to get the maximum value in HH.MM.SS format?

```
max(hms(times(cyc2022$ride_length)))
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In unpaste(times, sep = fmt$sep, fnames = fmt$periods, nfields = 3) :
  62 entries set to NA due to wrong number of fields
2: In convert.times(times., fmt) :
  157 time-of-day entries out of range set to NA
3: In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
  Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs

 max(times(cyc2022$ride_length))
Time in days:
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In unpaste(times, sep = fmt$sep, fnames = fmt$periods, nfields = 3) :
  62 entries set to NA due to wrong number of fields
2: In convert.times(times., fmt) :
  157 time-of-day entries out of range set to NA

max(hms(as.numeric(cyc2022$ride_length)))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
  Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `lubridate`. arranged in order of descending duration length:

```
df <- data.frame(durations = c("00:32:15","02:12:45","12:00:00"))

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(durations = as.duration(hms(durations))) %>%
  arrange(desc(durations))
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data

```
cyc2022
  ride_length dat
1    12:23:22   3
2    09:21:45   2
3    23:23:22   1
```

Using `readr`s `parse_time`

```
library(readr)

cyc2022[which.max(parse_time(cyc2022$ride_length)),]
  ride_length dat
3    23:23:22   1
```

get just the value with

```
max(cyc2022$ride_length)
[1] "23:23:22"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by using the command below. I doublechecked the result.

```
> max_time <- max(cyc2022$ride_length)
> max_time 
>[1] "99:13:00"
```